# Javascript : how to preserve newlines with textContent in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea, contenteditable

I have a `div contenteditable` in my web page. 
When you type some text inside the `div contenteditable`, the text is reproduced in a hidden textarea for the post treatment (form method="post" action="...").

For that, I retrieve the text from the `div contenteditable` by using `innerText` in Chrome, IE, and Safari, and `textContent` in Firefox.

The problem is when I type newlines (by typing Enter key) inside the `div contenteditable`, the newlines don't appear in the textarea, all the text in the textarea appear in one line.

Here the source code, very simple :

```
<style type="text/css">

.textarea{  
overflow: hidden;
resize: none;
width: 100%;
white-space: pre-line;
border: solid #cccccc 1px ;
height: 34px;
}

</style>

<form style="width:500px;" method="post">

    Div contenteditable :
    <div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" onkeyup='copy_text_in_textarea(this);'></div>

    <br>Textarea :
    <textarea rows="2" class="textarea" id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*Function to reproduce div text in textarea :*/
function copy_text_in_textarea(this_contenteditable)
{       
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = this_contenteditable.textContent;       
}

</script>
```

You can try it with firefox here : https://jsfiddle.net/Ls6j041g/

So how to preserve the newlines for the textarea ?

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: Because the new lines are new divs and you are just reading the text.

Comment: Ok, but how to make appear newlines in textarea ?

Comment: I found a trick : use `innerHTML` instead of `textContext` and replace `<br>` tags by `\n` and replace `&nbsp;` tokens by a normal space `" "`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use .innerText instead.

```js
function go() {
   console.log(document.querySelector('#ok').innerText);
}
```

```html
<span id="ok" contenteditable="true">Some Text<br/>with newlines
</span>
<button onclick="go()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use FF 42.0 on Windows 8.
On FireFox, I use function html() instead of textContent (innerText does not work).
In div contenteditable when we press enter it append "<br>" tag to div content.
So I try to convert <br> tag to new line "\n" in javascript:

```
JS script:
jQuery.br2nl = function(varTest){
    return varTest.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
};
isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
if(isFirefox == true) {
    message = $("#_chatText").html();
    message = $.br2nl(message);
    document.getElementById("_chatText").innerHTML = message;
    message = document.getElementById("_chatText").textContent;
}
My HTML <div>
<div contentEditable="true" id="_chatText"></div>
```